# Copper tubing for refrigerator

Tags: plumbing, water, refrigerator

My copper tubing for the water line to my refrigerator became slightly bent while I was installing it is it a big deal should I buy new copper tubing?

Comment: If it were me, I'd replace it with nonmetallic tubing.  But then again, I hate flexible copper tubing.  Most fridge manufactures recommend pulling out the fridge, and cleaning behind it.  This repeated movement is not so good for copper tubing, commonly resulting in kinks, bends, and other damage to the tubing.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how slight you mean by slightly.

Comment: Did not crease. It did create a flat spot on one side of the tubing. No sharp corners.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  As long as the icemaker still functions you're good.

Comment: If the tube is bent again, it will bend in the same spot.  Use care, or stiffen that area somehow to protect it.

Answer (score 1):

Copper work hardens, so every time you move that line it will become stiffer and more prone to kinking.  A replacement copper tube will be "dead soft" and easier to work with.  If you have the fridge back where you want it and the kinks have not produced a sharp spot (a flat is okay) then you're fine.  You might want to buy a replacement to have on hand if you have to move the fridge again.